# Formula cannot be cast to Column happen with spring boot

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I have two tables, bookshelf and book. bookshelf has an array of integer that stores key to book.
Entities and tables are defined as follow.

```
Table "public.bookshelf”
       Column        |              Type              |                     Modifiers                        | Storage  | Stats target |               Description
---------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------
id                   | integer                        | not null default nextval(‘bookshelf_seq'::regclass)  | plain    |              |
section              | character varying(255)         |                                                      | extended |              |
book_ids             | integer[]                      |                                                      | extended |              |                     

@Entity(name = "BookShelf")
@Table(name = "bookshelf")
public class BookShelf {
    @Id
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String section;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bookShelf")
    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
}

Table "public.book”
       Column        |              Type              |                     Modifiers                     | Storage  | Stats target |               Description
---------------------+--------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+------------------------------------------
id                   | integer                        | not null default nextval(‘book_seq'::regclass)    | plain    |              |
name                 | character varying(255)         |                                                   | extended |              |                                         

@Entity(name = "Book")
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {
    @Id
    @Setter
    @Getter
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("select b.id from bookshelf b where id = any(b.book_ids)")
    private BookShelf bookShelf ;
}
```

I'm getting `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.mapping.Formula cannot be cast to org.hibernate.mapping.Column`

I did a little test using hibernate alone and didn't see this issue, so I guess this might be a spring thing but getting rid of spring isn't the option.

Here is my dependencies

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1212</version>
</dependency>
```